# Calculate the data cache miss rate from the given code

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Consider the execution of the follow C code snippets (int: 32 bits) on a CPU with a single 32KB data cache and 128 byte cacheline (assume there is no prefetching of cachelines). What is the cache miss rate (%) of the following:

1.

```
int N = 64;
int a[N*N];
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      a[i*N+j] = i*j;
```

2. 

```
int N = 512;
int a[N*N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      a[i*N+j] = i*j;
```

I'm unsure how to approach these problems. I would have thought since the stride length exceeds the cacheline, both cases would miss everytime.

Comment: `j` increments by 1 each iteration of the inner loop, so there is some locality there.

Comment: N is a power of 2, so presumably version 1 is going to hit the worst case for aliasing and evict lines before coming back to them again.  version 2 is accessing contiguous memory.  Notice that version 2 has the loops inverted, with `j` as the inner, unlike version 1.